# Ultimate Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using this recyclerview
https://github.com/cymcsg/UltimateRecyclerView

It is able to compile but when it is loading in the device (genymotion)
I am getting this error

```
08-22 11:05:18.904    2112-2112/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.legalapp.bharath.legalapp_test, PID: 2112
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.legalapp.bharath.legalapp_test/com.legalapp.bharath.legalapp_test.Directory}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateRecyclerview
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateRecyclerview
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.legalapp.bharath.legalapp_test.Directory.onCreate(Directory.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateRecyclerview" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.legalapp.bharath.legalapp_test-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.legalapp.bharath.legalapp_test.Directory.onCreate(Directory.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateRecyclerview
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 23 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

I just included this in the build.gradle file and it synced properly with out any issue then I added this

```
<com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateRecyclerview
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateRecyclerView"></com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateRecyclerview>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using v for view in uppercase
use 
com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateRecyclerView
instead of
com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateRecyclerview